# How to represent DB null values in grid view

Tags: c#, asp.net

i need to fetch some records from database and then bind it to a grid view.

But , in the data i am fetching from DB, there are some null values

So, Inorder to avoid type casting error , i am using a function to avoid cast error.

```
public static T GetValue<T>(object o)
{
    T val = default(T);

    if (o != null && o != DBNull.Value)
    {
        val = (T)o;
    }
    return val;
}
```

But, when i am binding to grid , it is showing as o for columns of type long . But, i need

to show as no value  or nothing . Is it possible , if so please give your sugesstions

Comment: please post complete code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you just need to use `long?` instead of `long` as your generic parameter. I'm assuming you're currently doing something like:

```
long val = GetValue<long>(someDataField);
```

Just change that up to use the `Nullable<long>` type, and you'll get `null` back, and that should work in your grid.

```
long? val = GetValue<long?>(someDataField);
```